# Using YouTube Data API v3 to get YouTube title/views/thumbnail

Tags: android, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm new to the whole YouTube Data API v3 in android. So far, I'm using AsyncTask`HttpURLConnection` and `BufferedReader` to build a string response from API and then parsing it to JSON Object. I've read that there's a library that I can use instead of this, but  I found no android examples of using it.

Here's my code so far:

```
    public class TestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private Context mContext;
    private String mUrl;

    public TestAsyncTask(Context context, String url) {
        mContext = context;
        mUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        test = findViewById(R.id.test).toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String resultString = null;
        resultString = getJSON(mUrl);

        return resultString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strings) {
        super.onPostExecute(strings);
        test = strings;
        parseJSON(test);


    }

    private String getJSON(String url) {
        HttpURLConnection c = null;
        try {
            URL u = new URL(url);
            c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.connect();
            int status = c.getResponseCode();
            switch (status) {
                case 200:
                case 201:
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line+"\n");
                    }
                    br.close();
                    return sb.toString();
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return ex.toString();
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                try {
                    c.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    //disconnect error
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void parseJSON (String jsonStr){

        TextView testview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            MainActivity.object = obj;

        }

        catch (JSONException ex){

            testview.setText("Błąd" + ex.toString());

        }



    }
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Ah, how to use that Android/Java library to the same :)

Comment: Have you found the library? It would be better if you include it's link to your post for the community to help you better. :)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtube/v3

Comment: [See this blog](http://javatechig.com/android/youtubeplayerview-example-in-android-using-youtube-api)